# Are there any efficient methods to manually factor a quadratic in two variables?

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections, factoring, quadratic-forms

For a quadratic in two variables, $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$ may be factored into the form $(p_1x+q_1y+r_1)(p_2x+q_2y+r_2)$ given that $\det\begin{bmatrix}a & b/2 & d/2\\ b/2 & c & e/2\\d/2 & e/2 & f \end{bmatrix}=0 $.

By expanding out the general factored form:

$\begin{align}&(p_1x+q_1 y+r_1)(p_2x+q_2 y+r_2) \\ = &\,p_1p_2x^2+(p_1q_2+p_2q_1)xy+q_1q_2y^2+(p_1r_2+p_2r_1)x+(q_1r_2+q_2r_1)y+r_1r_2\end{align}$

It can be noted through comparison of coefficients:

$\begin{cases}a=p_1p_2 \\
b=p_1q_2+p_2q_1 \\
c=q_1q_2 \\
d=p_1r_2+p_2r_1 \\
e=q_1r_2+q_2r_1 \\
f=r_1r_2 \end{cases} \\ $

One method to determine the values for $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2, r_1, r_2$ would be through guessing and checking values that satisfy all six conditions. However, doing such a method manually is inefficient. For the univariate case, there exist several methods such as decomposition, slide and divide, as well as the quadratic formula to determine the values in a more systematic manner. Does there exist a similar procedure for the bivariate case?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think most univariate quadratic (even if with integer coeffcients) are factorizable, let alone easily so.

Comment: Hopefully someone will write a fuller answer, but basically, a better method hinges on the fact that the degree-2 homogeneous parts must necessarily be equal, so that $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=(p_1x+q_1y)(p_2x+q_2y)$.

Comment: @GregMartin  I answered with a general method  that relies on taking a symmetric matrix $H$  and finding nonsingular $P$  with $P^T H P = D$  diagonal.  I may have chosen a  discouraging example.

Answer (score 2):

I made up a problem, I think I will leave in the variable $z$
It is Sylvester's Law of Inertia that says the matrix $D$   will include a zero on the diagonal. See

[http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brookfield_Factoring_Forms_2016.pdf](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Brookfield_Factoring_Forms_2016.pdf)

$$66x^2 + 40 y^2 + 82 z^2 + 88 yz + 72 zx  + 96 xy$$
As I made it up, I know this one does factor. If you have trouble completing the square, there is an algorithm of Lagrange;

The matrix identity called $Q^T D Q = H$  says the original from is equal to
$$   66 \left(x + \frac{8}{11}y +  \frac{6}{11}z  \right)^2   +   \frac{56}{11} \left( y +  \frac{7}{2}z \right)^2  $$

Let us write this
$$  \frac{1}{11} \left(6 \left(11x + 8y + 6z  \right)^2   +   56 \left( y +  \frac{7}{2}z \right)^2 \right) $$

or
$$  \frac{1}{11} \left(\sqrt 6 \left(11x + 8y + 6z  \right)   + i  \sqrt{56} \left( y +  \frac{7}{2}z \right) \right)  \left(\sqrt 6 \left(11x + 8y + 6z  \right)   - i\sqrt   {56} \left( y +  \frac{7}{2}z \right) \right)$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 36 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 196 }{ 11 }  \\ 
36 &  \frac{ 196 }{ 11 }  & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  &  -  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 196 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 196 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 686 }{ 11 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 56 }{ 11 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 11 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
66 & 48 & 36 \\ 
48 & 40 & 44 \\ 
36 & 44 & 82 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Unrelated, but didn't know you were at UTSA.

Comment: @SeanRoberson  not me, my grad school friend Dmitry Gokhman.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you can multiply the first factor by a constant $\alpha$ and divide the second one by the same number, and you get the original polynomial. So wlog assume $a\ne 0$. Then you can choose $p_1=1$ and $p_2=a$. Look at the next two equations:
$$b=p_1q_2+p_2q_1=q_2+aq_1\\c=q_1q_2$$multiply the last equation by $a$:
$$aq_1+q_2=b\\(aq_1)q_2=ac$$
So $aq_1$ and $q_2$ are solutions of the quadratic $$z^2-bz+ac=0$$
You can also now find $r_1$ and $r_2$ from the fourth and fifth equations (linear system of two equations with two variables).